# Unsigned fixed point rationals

Tags: signal-processing, fixed-point

Why unsigned fixed point rational has the range **2^a - 2^-b**? Where a represents integer bits, and b represents fractional bits of the given number.

How I can determine the max value, unsigned fixed point rational can give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum distance representable is defined for the fractional part: 2^-b

The maximum number, will be how much times that minimum distance can be added, that will be **2^nbits-1** times (the amount of numbers that can be represented minus 1 because of 0)

Max range: **(2^nbits-1)*2^-b**

With some math mangling

> nbits=a+b,
>
> (2^nbits-1)*2^-b = 2^(a+b)-1*2^-b=2^a*2^b*2^-b+2^-b=**2^a*2^-b**

Example:

> Q(2,30)
>
> nbits=32
>
> range  0 /  2^2 - 2^-30
>
> minimum distance:  **2^-30,**
>
> amount of numbers that can be represented: **2^32**